# javascript on change function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Product page</title>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <style>
      /* Basic Styling */
        html, body {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }

        .container {
          max-width: 1200px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          padding: 15px;
          display: flex;
        }

        /* Columns */
        .left-column {
          width: 65%;
          position: relative;
        }

        .right-column {
          width: 35%;
          margin-top: 60px;
        }


        /* Left Column */
        .left-column img {
          width: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          opacity: 0;
          transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }

        .left-column img.active {
          opacity: 1;
        }


        /* Right Column */

        /* Product Description */
        .product-description {
          border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E8EE;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .product-description span {
          font-size: 12px;
          color: #358ED7;
          letter-spacing: 1px;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        .product-description h1 {
          font-weight: 300;
          font-size: 52px;
          color: #43484D;
          letter-spacing: -2px;
        }
        .product-description p {
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 300;
          color: #86939E;
          line-height: 24px;
        }

        /* Product Configuration */
        .product-color span,
        .cable-config span {
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: 400;
          color: #86939E;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        /* Cable Configuration */
        .cable-choose {
          margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .cable-choose button {
          border: 2px solid #E1E8EE;
          border-radius: 6px;
          padding: 13px 20px;
          font-size: 14px;
          color: #5E6977;
          background-color: #fff;
          cursor: pointer;
          transition: all .5s;
        }

        .cable-choose button:hover,
        .cable-choose button:active,
        .cable-choose button:focus {
          border: 2px solid #86939E;
          outline: none;
        }

        .cable-config {
          border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E8EE;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .cable-config a {
          color: #358ED7;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 12px;
          position: relative;
          margin: 10px 0;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        .cable-config a:before {
          content: "?";
          height: 15px;
          width: 15px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          border: 2px solid rgba(53, 142, 215, 0.5);
          display: inline-block;
          text-align: center;
          line-height: 16px;
          opacity: 0.5;
          margin-right: 5px;
        }

        /* Product Price */
        .product-price {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
        }

        .product-price span {
          font-size: 26px;
          font-weight: 300;
          color: #43474D;
          margin-right: 20px;
        }

        .btn {
          display: inline-block;
          background-color: #FFB6C1;
          border-radius: 6px;
          font-size: 16px;
          color: #FFFFFF;
          text-decoration: none;
          padding: 12px 30px;
          transition: all .5s;
        }
        .btn:hover {
          background-color: #ff5733;
        }

        /* Responsive */
        @media (max-width: 940px) {
          .container {
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-top: 60px;
          }

          .left-column,
          .right-column {
            width: 100%;
          }

          .left-column img {
            width: 300px;
            right: 0;
            top: -65px;
            left: initial;
          }
        }

        @media (max-width: 535px) {
          .left-column img {
            width: 220px;
            top: -85px;
          }
        }
    </style>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />

  </head>

  <body>
    <main class="container">

      <!-- Left Column / Headphones Image -->
      {%  for p in products  %}
      <div class="left-column">
        <!-- <img data-image="black" src="images/black.png" alt="">
        <img data-image="blue" src="images/blue.png" alt=""> -->
        <img data-image="red" class="active" src="{{p.image.url}}" alt="">
      </div>
      


      <!-- Right Column -->
      <div class="right-column">

        <!-- Product Description -->
        <div class="product-description">
          <span>{{p.vendor}}</span>
          <h1>{{p.title}}</h1>
          <p>{{p.description}}</p>
        </div>
        {%  endfor  %}

        <!-- Product Configuration -->
        <div class="product-configuration">

          <!-- Product Color -->
          
          <div class="product-color">
            <span>Color</span>
            {%  for c in colors  %}

            <div class="color-choose">
              <input type="checkbox" onchange="colorID('{{c.id}}')" id="checkbox1" style="display: none;">
              <label for="checkbox1"value="✔" style="display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 40px; background-color: {{c.code}}; border-radius: 50%;border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer;float: left; margin-right: 10px;box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.33);"></label>
            </div>
            {%  endfor  %}

          </div>
          


          <!-- Cable Configuration -->
          
          <div class="cable-config">
            <span>Sizes</span>
            {%  for s in sizes  %}
            <div class="cable-choose">
              <button>{{s.name}}</button>
              <!-- <button>Coiled</button>
              <button>Long-coiled</button> -->
            </div>
            {%  endfor  %}

            <!-- <a href="#">How to configurate your headphones</a> -->
          </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
        

        <!-- Product Pricing -->
          {%  for p in products  %}
          <div class="product-price">
            <span>Our Price:{{p.price}}</span>
            <del>M.R.P: {{p.old_price}}</del>
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Add to cart</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
          </div>
          {%  endfor  %}
      </div>
      
    </main>
    
           <!-- Related Products Section -->
           <div class="related-products">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <h2>Related Products</h2>
            </div>
    
            {% for p in products %}
            <div class="showcase">
                <div class="showcase-banner">
                    <img src="{{ p.image.url }}" alt="{{ p.title }}" width="300" class="product-img default">
                    <p class="showcase-badge">{{ p.get_percentage|floatformat:0 }}% off</p>
                </div>
                <div class="showcase-content">
                    <a href="#" class="showcase-category">{{ p.category }}</a>
                    <a href="#"><h3 class="showcase-title">{{ p.title }}</h3></a>
                    <div class="price-box">
                        <p class="price">{{ p.price }}</p>
                        <del>{{ p.old_price }}</del>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Add to cart</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    {%  for i in colors  %}
    <script>

      function colorID(){
        window.location.href =window.location.pathname + `?color=${{i.id}}`
      }

    </script>
    {%  endfor  %}
  </body>
</html>
```

In the script section color id is taking same value for each of the checkboxes

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/prdcadfacebaa/?color=$4
```

In every cases the script is taking **?color=$4** the value of 4. You can see that In Input section I have taken the **onchange function** and I java script made it href with **?color** And the main problem is here The function is not taking the color ID unique.
[image: part1]
in **part1** image when i click on the first color it is showing 1
[image: part2]
in **part2** image when I clicking the next color it is marking as on 2....

Comment: There no language named `java script` there is `java` or `javascript`. there is no hypothetical "scripting" language based on the java language

Comment: sorry it is typing mistake. Please forgive me and give me the solution

Comment: please help me out!

Comment: Have you used your browser devtools inspect facility so see if there are errors in the console, also using eg console.log to check what actual values are being created? ie what debugging have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I findout the solution I made little changes in code
**Instade of**

```
{%  for c in colors  %}

            <div class="color-choose">
              <input type="checkbox" onchange="colorID('{{c.id}}')" id="checkbox1" style="display: none;">
              <label for="checkbox1"value="✔" style="display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 40px; background-color: {{c.code}}; border-radius: 50%;border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer;float: left; margin-right: 10px;box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.33);"></label>
            </div>
            {%  endfor  %}
```

I changed this code to

```
<a href="?colorID={{c.code}}" style="display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 40px; background-color: {{c.code}}; border-radius: 50%; border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer; float: left; margin-right: 10px; box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);">
```

And I also remove the script

Answer (score 0):

So what i can read in your code this section here your looping over an array of colours and creating a script block in each iteration of the loop with the same function. this will cause issues. remove your for loop so you have one script block with the one colorID function.

```js
 {%  for i in colors  %} <== Remove
    <script>

      function colorID(){
        window.location.href =window.location.pathname + `?color=${{i.id}}`
      }

    </script>
    {%  endfor  %} <== remove
```

the next issue i noticed is where your calling the colorID function here

`<input type="checkbox" onchange="colorID('{{c.id}}')" id="checkbox1" style="display: none;">`

so you call the function and give it a parameter but when you look at your colorID function it doesn't take any parameters. If you want this to work you should add the parameter to the function like this.

```js
function colorID(cID){
        window.location.href =window.location.pathname + '?color=' + cID;
      }
```

Also you where using ` in your script which I changed to ' I'm not a JS pro so I don't know if that's allowed or not, just didn't seem right to me. Everything else I'm going off basic principles.

Comment: It is not working. Still taking only one value

Comment: Please help me out!!!

Comment: Then you should debug each part separately, first place i would start is the onchange. remove the call to your colorID function and put alert('{{c.id}}') so the code would look like `onchange="alert('{{c.id}}')"` then test to see if the pop up comes up and the numbers are different. if the popup comes up all with the same number, there is something up with your data. Otherwise change the call as it was and move to the function. in the function add `console.log(cID);` and see if the data is changing. Good'ol fashion debugging. also check page source to make sure it's correct once processed.

Comment: I edited the output on the question please check it out, and the popup comes up all with the same number.

Comment: You should update the question to reflect your current code after changes you made. Also you should give us an output of the current value of the colors array. at this Point with the little information given its hard to determine the issues. Remember to use console.log() to output and test your values. even doing something as basic as printing the values your having trouble with to the page just to see if they are correct at that point helps. Basic debugging normally solves alot of these types of issues.